# Javascript compiled from coffeescript browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, browser, coffeescript

I want to find a list of compatible browsers, that support javascript compiled from coffeescript, and find out if this compiled code supports specific ECMAScript specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoffeeScript generates code that's compatible with all major browsers going back to IE6 =)